# Use rules to define links between concepts of two ontologies

Tags: ontology

Using protégé 4, I have created three differents ontologies: Process, tools, Raw material. Now, i want to define the relation between the concepts of these ontologies (for example: a specific task in the process ontology need the use of a specific tool). How can i do this using rules?

Comment: Decide which is your main ontology and then import the others in the main one and try creating your links.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to do it with rules

Comment: Explain your problem a bit more then. What does rules mean? What type of rules? Give an example. With your explanation, your problem seems straightforwards.

Comment: In protege, we have the possibility to define rules on the concept and properties of a single ontology for example: son(?x), hasParent(?x, ?y) -> father(?y) such that son, hasParent, father are elements of the same ontology. I want to do the same but with elements of different ontologies.
For example, given a recipe ontology describing the process of preparing cake, an ontology for ingredients and another for ustensils. For the task "spread dough" in the recipe ontology we use  "rolling pin" from the ustensil ontology. Using SWRL rules, how can i do it. is it possible to do so?

Comment: So then that is what I mentioned. You need to import it. If you look at all the big resources that they need to use external resources (e.g using PROV ontology to implement provenance information(https://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/#Collection)) they first import it and then they write new restrictions. Look at any extended ontology, this is the whole point of knowledge reuse.